# Storing FCM token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app which receives push notifications. I was wondering if there was a more straightforward method to store a FCM token and user ID on a external  db given that right now I'm writing my own `FirebaseInstanceIdService. sendRegistrationToServer` method. Like this

```java
public class TokenRegistrationService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // My custom manager
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String FCMToken) {
        // Here I can send FCMToken to my db
    }
}
```

Is there any other way for me to get the token and send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean a more straightforward way than extending `FirebaseInstanceIdService`. If so then you should note that the token is generated whether or not you extend this class.

To retrieve the token you can simply get an instance of InstanceID and call `getToken`.

```
String token = InstanceID.getInstance().getToken();
```

Also note that if you are not requesting the token in the `FirebaseInstanceIdService` `onTokenRefresh` callback, `getToken` will return null **if** the token retrieval process has not yet completed and will return the token once it has been retrieved.

The token retrieval happens as soon as your application starts so if you don't need the token very early on first run, calling `getToken` will likely be sufficient. If you need the token or refreshed versions as soon as they are available then you would need to extend `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and override `onTokenRefresh`.

Comment: is it secure to store the token and user info in mongo db instead of firebase database ?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there any other way for me to get the token and send it?*

For generating the registration token, I'm pretty sure there is no other way than just using the `FirebaseInstanceID` service.

For when sending the token to your server.. I'm not sure what the question is here. Isn't sending the token directly to your app server after it was generated straightforward enough? Or am I missing something?  Do expound.